# How to fix "?Itemid= in website address joomla"

Tags: web, joomla, joomla3.0

in joomla cms There is a big problam. "duplicate content" and "duplicate URL"

for exam this 
url: www.exam.com/component/content/frontpage
or
url: www.exam.com/component/users/login?Itemid=101

Even by making the menu URL yet These URL has work!
Or a much problam thing, itemid url has work! Even with sh404SEF extensions! this url for exam:  ?Itemid=135
Even this url is works in joomla orginal website!

Now, how fix that? Where is the problem?
tnx

Comment: This would be a good question to ask on the joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0):

you need to use canonical plugin to show the original address 
i think the best one is "canonical links all in one" :
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/canonical-links-all-in-one/